# Alternatives to execute a selenium script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, ghostdriver

I have a `selenium` script with `python 3`. I need to run it every day at 7AM for 5 minutes but I cannot leave my laptop on 24/7 just for it. What would be the easiest/best alternative?

I checked `Lambda AWS` but I am unable to install `chrome` (or the headless version of it) there and I have no experience with servers.

Comment: Are you able to provisioning an EC2 instance? Is your script compatible with headless browsers like phantomjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Lambda is a viable solution for your goal - especially if the script is going to have a small runtime. They have recently increased the maximum execution time to 15 minutes, so you should be ok.

Getting headless Chrome in Lambda (*in Python; it's full of JS/node.js solutions out there :)*) is doable - I myself have used successfully this project in the past - https://github.com/21Buttons/pychromeless

To schedule the execution at your desired time you could use [Amazon's CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html).

Comment: In my script I use functions like `find_element_by_xpath` or `click`. A headless chrome would be able to work with these selenium functions?

Comment: Yes, absolutely; pretty much everything in the selenium library is available to a headless browser.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a *Selenium* script with *Python 3* without installing a browser you can use the *GhostDriver*.

### [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver)

[**Ghost Driver**](https://www.guru99.com/selenium-with-htmlunit-driver-phantomjs.html) is an implementation of the *Remote WebDriver* protocol using *PhantomJS* as back-end. GhostDriver is designed to be integral part of PhantomJS itself with JavaScript API.

### [Additional WebDriver Capabilities through GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver#what-extra-webdriver-capabilities-ghostdriver-offers)

- `phantomjs.page.settings.SETTING = VALUE`
- `phantomjs.page.customHeaders.HEADER = VALUE`
- `phantomjs.page.whitelist`
- `phantomjs.page.blacklist`
- `unhandledPromptBehavior`
- `loggingPrefs`
- `phantomjs.binary.path`
- `phantomjs.ghostdriver.path`
- `phantomjs.cli.args`
- `phantomjs.ghostdriver.cli.args`

### Main Advantages of GhostDriver

- Screen Capture
- Page Automation
- Network Monitoring
- To run Unit tests on command line
- Combined with QUnit for the test suite

### An Example

- Code Block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/path/to/phantomjs')
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
  print(driver.title)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Google
  ```

Comment: So, how does a GhostDriver commerical answers the question "how & where to schedule daily recurring script executions"; and OP asking for AWS lambda you instruct him to set a driver executable that's for Windows?